simple route to 192.168.1.1 always ends up in loopback interface instead of eth0
I'm sshing to a raspberry pi over wlan0 and trying to connect to a modem at the ethernet interface.
Take a look at my table and my ip route get:
lz@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.33.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    10     0        0 eth0
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
lz@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route get 192.168.1.1
local 192.168.1.1 dev lo src 192.168.1.1 uid 1000
cache local

No matter what I tried, it always goes through the loopback interface.
ifconfig output:
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::____________  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ____________  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 346  bytes 15916 (15.5 KiB)
        RX errors 1  dropped 346  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 113  bytes 13414 (13.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I also tried cross interface:
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  1

network interfaces
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

Why the route always end up on the loopback?

192.168.1.1 belongs to the Pi. When you connect to it from within the Pi, this happens.

@KamilMaciorowski why it belongs to the pi? wlan0 is 192.168.33.6

And eth0 is 192.168.1.1.
